# NSPredicate - returning ever unique instance in a column

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I was wondering if there was a predicate to return every unique instance in a column.

Comment: Core Data doesn't have columns. Thinking of Core Data in SQL terms will lead to grief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the [`NSFetchRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html) to return uniques for you.  Take a look at its documentation.

Comment: That is originally what I attempted to use, setReturnsDistinctResults which uses propertiesToFetch. Problem is, I want to use a NSFetchedResultsController; not a NSDictionaryResultType, which is required, for the results.

Comment: You cannot return uniques and use the `NSFetchedResultsController` together. That is not the intended design. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I have a list of locations in a sqlite db. They have neighborhoods. I want the user to be able to search by neighborhoods. The neighborhoods populate a tableview. Problem is, I have dozens of each neighborhood. I just want one unique instance of each neighborhood.

Comment: Why don't you have relationships between locations and neighborhoods so that each location has one neighborhood and a neighborhood has many locations?  Sounds like a data model issue.

Comment: I ditched the NSFetchedResultsController and stored the data in an array, then made an NSSet of the array, then transferred the data back to the array. This seemed to work. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`@distinctUnionOfArrays` might work, depending on your situation: [Core Data - Getting Unique Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996279/core-data-getting-unique-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code used to solve the problem.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)fetchNeighborhoods {

    ProjectNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectNameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bar" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"neighborhood" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Get array of results.
    NSMutableArray *theResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    // Grab unique neighborhoods through NSSet.
    NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:[theResults valueForKey:@"neighborhood"]];
    // Dump NSSet uniques into new array.
    NSMutableArray *sortedResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uniqueElements allObjects]]; 
    // Sort the results alphabetically.
    sortedResults = [[sortedResults sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] mutableCopy];
    // Output unique results for verification.   
    for(int i = 0; i < [sortedResults count];i++){
        NSLog(@"%d. %@", i+1, [sortedResults objectAtIndex:i]); 
    }

    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return sortedResults;
}
```